# Regular Expression Visual Studio 2013

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

I have a project in Visual Studio 2013 and I am facing issues with 3-part naming.
I found out that a workaround is to replace `[DB]` of `[DB].[Schema].[Table]` from global variable `[$(DatabaseName)]`. But the problem is there are some statements which are like:

```
@cmd "SELECT * FROM [DB].[Schema].[Table]"
```

and there are comments too both single line comments and multi-line comments

EDIT:
I have lines like these:

- SELECT @cmd = ' INSERT PhoenixCommon.dbo.ObjectAdministration' +
- , @cmdFrom  = ' FROM   PhoenixCommon.dbo.ObjectAdministration oad' +
- ** 02/08/08   Ed White     Updated for PhoenixCommon DB
- --   FROM PhoenixCommon.dbo.UserAccount

In these lines I don't want to change "PheonixCommon" with "[$(DatabaseName)]"

but lines like this:

- JOIN PhoenixCommon.dbo.Object obj WITH (NOLOCK)
- UPDATE PhoenixCommon.dbo.Organization
- FROM   PhoenixCommon.dbo.Organization

In these type of lines I want to replace  PheonixCommon with [$(DatabaseName)]

Any suggestion how can I replace those `[DB]` (in this casePheonixCommon) from `[$(DatabaseName)]` using regular expression. Any other ideas are most welcome.

Comment: please elaborate your problem. what you are doing? any ADO.NET code?  where you are doing this. code behind page or aspx or somewhere else. and is it C# or VB?

Comment: I recommend regexhero.net for testing regular expressions.

Comment: @Balaji I updated the question. I am trying to import a SQL Server Project into VS2013 with SSDT tools to create an .sqlproj. I am not using C# or VB . All the files are SQL Scripts.